# migration failed with error: table.integer(...).references(...).on(...).OnDelete is not a function Knex.js postgres

Tags: javascript, psql, knex.js

I know I have postgres working and I have the username and password in the knexfile.js with the database name. Also psql is running. The problem I am I am having an issue trying to run this command with one of my tables. I tried a lot of differen't step liking adding table instead of on (I read that it's an alias. I tried foreign() instead of an integer() with no progress. Please help or maybe point out a flaw in my knowledge. Thank you

`knex migrate:latest`

I get this error

```
 Using environment: development 

 migration failed with error: table.string(...).references(...).on(...).OnDelete is not a function

migration file "20200525002912_personal_todos.js" failed    

    TypeError: table.integer(...).references(...).on(...).OnDelete is not a function
        at TableBuilder._fn (/home/misterjoe/personal_projects/group-note-todo-api/db/migrations/20200525002912_personal_todos.js:5:59)
```

Here's my personal_todos.js file migration

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('personal_todos', (table)=>{
    table.increments('id')
    table.integer('user_id').references('id').on('users').OnDelete('CASCADE');
    table.boolean('active').notNullable();
    table.string('start_time')
    table.string('end_time')
    table.string('header')
    table.string('body')
    table.integer('container_index').notNullable()
    table.integer('container_item_index').notNullable()
    table.timestamps(true,true);
    table.boolean('private')
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('personal_todos')
};
```

Also here's my users.js table

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', (table)=>{
      table.increments('id');
      table.string('first-name');
      table.string('last-name');
      table.string('username');
      table.string('email');
      table.string('password');
      table.integer('age');
      table.string('bio');
      table.string('gender');
      table.string('personalsecret1');
      table.string('personalsecret2');
      table.string('personalsecret3');
      table.string('colorScheme');
      table.binary('img');
      table.timestamps(true,true);
      table.boolean('payed');
      table.boolean('active');
      table.boolean('friends_can_see_private');
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('users')
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by removing the onDelete() and adding it back after running knex migrate:latest. I added in some more code and then it worked after.

Here's the code I hope it helps, and here are the steps

1. remove onDelete() run migrate:latest
2. add unsigned(). onDelete('CASCADE') and I also added in onUpdate('CASCADE') as well

then run knex migrate:latest